# WP 7.5 - Is it possible to create a small preloader project?

Tags: preloader, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7, xap

I would like to create a shell/preloader project for Windows Phone like the following:
http://pagebrooks.com/archive/2009/05/17/a-smaller-xap-preloader-for-silverlight.aspx

The issue here is that AssemblyPart.Load() doesn't exist on the phone.  Is there another way to create a similar system on WP Mango?

Comment: My guess that this is not possible, can you explain what do you want to do? Make a light first page and load all heavy assets on background thread later on.

Comment: And if your main page has assets that take a while to load you may be able to get away with showing a splash screen that looks like your main page (maybe an empty main page). This should give the user a perception of responsiveness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their are ways to give the appearance of being in the application and downloading the Heavy assets in the background.

My recent app opens with an image and when clicked, goes into animation. allowing things to download in the background making it more user friendly.
This is definitely more personal preference than anything,do an animation then host a small pop-up saying "Content Loading" but start the loading process before the animation. Allowing the content Load to be less time.

Your best bet is to try different things, and find what works best for you.
On another note, it isn't possible to access AssemblyPart.Load() on the windows Phone.

I hope this helps a little. :)